# $S_n$ is distributed according to $\sim \max\{V_i : 1\leq i \leq n\}$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables

If we have a random variable $S_n \sim R_1+\cdots +R_n$ where $R_j\sim \operatorname{Exp}(j\lambda)$ and independent, is it true that also $S_n \sim \max\{V_i : 1\leq i \leq n\}$ with $V_i \overset{\text{iid}}\sim \operatorname{Exp}(\lambda)$.

I got:
\begin{align*}
P(\max\{V_1,...,V_n\}\leq k)&=P(V_1\leq k, ...,V_n\leq k) \\
&=P(V_1\leq k)\cdot \ldots \cdot P(V_n\leq k) \\
&=(1-e^{-\lambda k})^n
\end{align*}

But how is does relate to the sum of $R_i$'s? Can someone help?

Comment: Yes, independent. not identically distributed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show it by induction on $n$. The base case $n = 1$ is trivial. So assume it is true for some integer $n$ i.e. $S_n = R_1 + \ldots + R_n \sim \max\{V_1, \ldots, V_n\}$. Now consider $S_{n + 1} = R_1 + \cdots + R_n + R_{n + 1}$. Note $S_n$ is independent of $R_{n + 1}$; so for $x \geq 0$ you can write:
\begin{align*}
&P[S_{n + 1} \leq x] = P[S_n + R_{n + 1} \leq x] = \int_0^x P[S_n \leq x - t]f_{R_{n + 1}}(t) \ dt \\
= &\int_0^x (1 - e^{-\lambda (x - t)})^n \times (n + 1)\lambda e^{-(n + 1)\lambda t} \ dt = -e^{-(n + 1)\lambda t} (1 - e^{-\lambda (x - t)})^{n + 1} \Big |_{t = 0}^{t = x} \\
= &(1 - e^{-\lambda x})^{n + 1}
\end{align*} and of course for $x < 0$ the above is $0$. This is clearly the cdf of $\max\{V_1, \ldots, V_n, V_{n + 1}\}$, as you have already derived. And this completes the induction.

Comment: Sometimes you just need the right method! Thanks a million!